# Read-only file system: MongoDB Cluster on Kubernetes using Helm charts

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I launched a MongoDB replica set on Kubernetes (GKE as well as kubeadm). I faced no problems with the pods accessing the storage.
However, when I used Helm to deploy the same, I face this problem. 
When I run this command-
(

> kubectl describe po mongodb-shard1-0 --namespace=kube-system
>   )

(Here mongodb-shard1-0 is the first and only pod (of the desired three) which was created)
I get the error-
[Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUVNc.png)

> Error: failed to start container "mongodb-shard1-container": Error
>   response from daemon: error while creating mount source path
>   '/mongo/data': mkdir /mongo: read-only file system

I noticed one major difference between the two ways of creating MongoDB cluster (without Helm, and with Helm)- when using Helm, I had to create a service account and install the Helm chart using that service account. Without Helm, I did not need that.

I used different mongo docker images, I faced the same error every time.

Can anybody help why I am facing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Docker exports [volumes from filesystem](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) using -v command line option. i.e. -v /var/tmp:/tmp

Can you check if the containers/pods are writing to shared volumes,  not to the root filesystem?